# Recover maven central publishing rights

Tags: maven

I believe I created a Sonatype.org account some years ago, back before it went from .org to .com. Their modern site doesn't seem to recognize me. (Password reset does nothing.)

So I created a new account and tried to register my domain, but they say it's already registered. There are no published artifacts (not surprising).

Does anyone know how I can wrest control back? Is there any way to get a support ticket? I tried navigating their system, but all I got was a bunch of FAQs and a "check twitter to see if we're down".